# Получить доступ к  самописному CMS сайта

Tags: php, cms

Нужно получить доступ к  самописному CMS сайта. Доступ к ftp и БД есть. А пароль не знаю.

Защел в БД что б сменить пароль админа, а пароль храниться в зашифрованном виде: aaa88e68a06b12b08c7c03842aa58ab6:68

Что значит :68? это какой то специальный хеш или ключ для расшифровки?

Comment: а какая CMS?

Comment: Это важно? Я же написал "к самописному CMS"

Comment: Не совсем понял смысл фразы "доступ к БД и ftp есть, а пароль не знаю". Если вы зашли в БД, то как, если без пароля? Или пароль от админки? Если так, то что мешает снести вручную пароль и заново зарегистрироваться в админке, если CMS самописная и есть исходный код??

Comment: CMS самописный, исходников много - времени нет ковыряться.

В БД другой пароль, а для входу в панель управления - другой.

Comment: @Скрыто1, без анализа файлов никто не скажет, как пароль хранится. Но точка сверки паролей выясняется минут за пять.

Comment: Да

Comment: @Скрыто1, простите, не заметил. Тогда получается, что вы просите нас сказать, как у вас организовано хранение данных пароля? Да туда записать что угодно можно, все ограничивается только фантазией разработчика

Comment: Это гениаально. нет времени ковыряться,но есть время задавать вопрос и описывать занимать время свое и остальных. Закрыть бы вопрос, за лень. Да и просто за абсолютную его бесполезность

Answer (score 2):

Копайте вглубь php файлов, ищите функции авторизации и формирования запроса к БД таблице пользователей для проверки соответствия пароля. К примеру у меня после проверки валидности введённых данных, в БД отсылается запрос `select id from tab_users where login = $login and password = md5('тутсоль'.$password.'и тут ещё соль')`